# Excel VBA hide columns based on dropdown selection and checkbox selection

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a possibility that the two codes below can be combined to so that if the checkbox is selected and the D11 cell has a specific selection then it would hide columns based on the two selections?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$D$11" Then
        If Target.Value = "A" Or Target.Value = "C" Then
           Sheets("Worksheet").Columns("BL:CH").Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Value = "C" Then
Sheets("Worksheet").Columns("BL:BY").Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Sheets("Worksheet").Columns("BZ:CH").Hidden = Not Me.CheckBox1.Value  (TO UNHIDE SPECIFIC COLUMS ONLY WHEN CHECKED)

End Sub
```

Comment: Please make sure to format your code properly for readability. The code block gets cut off halfway.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I got to work.  Thank you

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$D$11" Then
    If Target.Value = "A" Or Target.Value = "B" Then
        Sheets("Worksheet").Columns("BL:CH").Hidden = True
    ElseIf Target.Value = "C" And Not Me.CheckBox1.Value Then
        Sheets("Worksheet").Columns("BL:BY").Hidden = False
    ElseIf Target.Value = "C" And Me.CheckBox1.Value Then
        Sheets("Worksheet").Columns("BL:BY").Hidden = True
        Sheets("Worksheet").Columns("BZ:CH").Hidden = False
    End If
 End If
End Sub
```